# Looking to make a questions and answer batch file that will enter in to location

Tags: batch-file

I am kind of new at this but what I am trying to do is when you run the batch file it will ask you what user account. Than when you enter the user account it will bring you into that account location. I feel like I am close but not to sure what I am missing.

```
@ECHO OFF 
Title Enter Users Profile 
color 4f

cd C:\Users\ dir
Set /p  %User%= Account:
%User%== cd C:\Users\%user%\
```

Comment: Open a command window, and figure out how (without the batch file) to execute the commands you need. Then use that information to try and write the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the hack you want to achieve with this but here is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
:enterUser
SET /p usr=enter user account:
IF EXIST C:\Users\%usr% (
    CD C:\Users\%usr%
) ELSE (
    ECHO User not found!
    ECHO Try again!
    GOTO enterUser
)
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set /p  %User%= Account:
```

This is incorrect syntax, because %User is expanded, but has no value, so you end up trying to prompt;

```
Set /p  = Account:
```

Which won't set anything.
Just use;

```
set /p User= Account:
```

Also the last line in your script is

```
%User%== cd C:\Users\%user%\
```

Which makes me think you forgot to put `if` and the corresponding commands after it.

It's also good practice to put quotes around your variables, in case a few odd symbols or, more often spaces mess things up, which can easily happen in most commands that use user/file/folder names.

And as I always mention, if you plan to have others using this, check if they just press enter after the `set /p` with

```
 if not defined User (
  echo Error: Empty Input
  pause
  goto :top
)
```

MichealS's code should be sufficient, I just wanted to explain a few odditied of your code.